# Should I continue to Power Up my Pokemon, or evolve it ASAP?

Tags: pokemon-go

So for some reason I have caught, like, a dozen Pidgey's. I have mostly been handing them over to the professor and have a good supply of Pidgey candy. I also have one Pidgey with relatively high CP that I've powered up a few times with stardust. I see from the arc around it that it looks like there's a maximum value to powering it up. I also have the option to make it evolve right now.

Is there a reason to power up a Pokemon before evolving them (or vice versa?) what's the best practice here?

Comment: Possible dup of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272730/does-it-make-a-cp-difference-if-you-feed-candies-before-or-after-evolving

Comment: @Dragonrage I can't flag it :/

Comment: @Alex, the other question has not had an answer, yet. As a result, it can not be used as an 'original' in a duplicate vote

Comment: @Timelord64 ok. It's giving me that message now