# Is it worth more to evolve or upgrade Pokemon? Should I spend on upgrades or save for evolution?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am new in this game so I can't understand what is more worth evolution or upgrade? I have Charmander as a starting Pokemon and I upgraded it 2 times. Is it worth to save for his evolution?

Comment: See here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272730/does-it-make-a-cp-difference-if-you-feed-candies-before-or-after-evolving

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you level up your trainer you will find pokemon with higher CP. This means next time you find a Charmander you will have a better chance of it having a higher CP than the one you started with (eg I recently found a Squirtle with 198CP). So saving candies and stardust for a higher level Charmander would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Kiwi's answer:
The CP gained by a power up is influenced by the stage of evolution.
A maxed out Pokemon like Charizard or Hitmonchan will get more CP per Powerup than a Charmander.